# Why am I getting a "mergeCursor" object instead of a "string"?

Tags: java, android

When I execute the code below, I would like to get `text="All"`, as its visible value is that, but all the time I'm getting

`String text = "android.database.MergeCursor@88a4aaa"`

The code:

```java
String[] from = new String[]{"type"};
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
Cursor cursorTypes = coctelsOpenHelper.getTypes();
        //Add "All" option to the spinner
        MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "type"});
        matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[] { "0", getString(R.string.title_all_drinks) });

        MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] { matrixCursor, cursorTypes });

        spinnerType = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDrinkType);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mergeCursor, from, to,0);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerType.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinnerType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
               //When I try to debug, the text value is the given above, a MergeCursor
                text = ((String)spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString());

                selectedItem = position;
                addSelection();
                //This ones don't have anything in common with the adapter from the spinner, are for a RecyclerView
                initializeData();
                initializeAdapter();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
            }
        });
```

And no, "text" is not being used anymore, so it's value hasn't changed, and I've also tried with

```
spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

but got same result.

All I wanted to do, is get the string value of the text on the Spinner, and compare it to `R.string.myvalue` with `text.equals(getString(R.string.myvalue))`

Comment: Maybe the actual question should be why do you get a `MergeCursor` instead of a `String`.

Comment: Didn't thought about it, I think you're right

Comment: Seems you figured it out. Instead of addding it to your question post your own answer (and accept it in two days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** As the problem was the `MergeCursor` (I needed it for adding a line to my Cursor), I ended not using a `simple cursor adapter` for the spinner, but a `ArrayAdapter`, previously adding my custom row with the "all" text, and lately adding the Cursor lines one by one to the ArrayList, and that way I didn't get any problems.

```
spinnerType = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDrinkType);
    //Get the different types of drinks
    Cursor cursorTypes = coctelsOpenHelper.getTypes();

    //Add "All" field to the spinner, for that "all" field is added first to the ArrayList,
    // and later each item of the cursor
    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<>();

    spinnerArray.add(getString(R.string.title_all_drinks));
    for(cursorTypes.moveToFirst(); !cursorTypes.isAfterLast(); cursorTypes.moveToNext()) {
        spinnerArray.add(cursorTypes.getString(1));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerType.setAdapter(adapter);


    spinnerType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {                
            text = spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString();

            addSelection();
            initializeData();
            initializeAdapter();
        }
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of your variable?

Comment: text is a String

Comment: it says
`android.database.MergeCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: Yes i think @seond is right. The text you are getting is because of `MergeCursor`

Comment: Yeah, it seems that, but I don't know what to do to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adapter =
            ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOf("1", "2", "3"))

        spinner.adapter = adapter

        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                logDebug(spinner.getItemAtPosition(position))
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.`
Tried with `setOnItemClickListener`, as there is no `onItemCliclListener`

Comment: The difference is that you send a message to the log? (I'm asking only, I don't know really). Sry, but I don't get more differences, maybe because I don't know how to use Kotlin
I updated the first post, maybe you find something else